# I am trying to create javascript that will make an element change when hovered over

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this javascript. I want it to make an html element get larger when the mouse hovers over it and back to normal size when it the mouse leaves it.

```js
let first = document.getElementsByClassName('contact');

let bigger = function (event) {
  event.style.maxHeight = "10rem";
}

let normal = function (event) {
  event.style.maxHeight = "8rem";
}

let changeSize = function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
  button.addEventListener('mouseout', normal);
}

first.forEach(changeSize);
```

This is the javascript I wrote and i dont understadn why its not working.

Not sure what to change to make it work

Comment: You're setting a style on an event; I don't think that's going to work as you expect it to. I would use a css `:hover` pseudoselector instead.

Comment: true I knew css would be an easier way to do this but wanted to try getting the javascript to work for learning purposes

Comment: Should be `event.target.style.maxHeight`

Comment: also tried adding .target but it didn't work

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName() ` returns a live `HTMLCollection`, which does not have a `forEach()` method.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\philc\OneDrive\Documents\Coding_Projects\Portfolio Project\resources\index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)

Comment: this is what i got apparent it says document is not defined when it should refer to the html right?

Comment: How did you run your code? It looks like you are using nodejs

Comment: oooooo okay so i cant use for each on getElementByClassName. would a for loop work better?

Comment: What does your html look like and how are you including your JS with your html?

Comment: A for-loop or "force" it into an array with `Array.from(first).forEach(changeSize)`

Comment: Is the contents of your elements large enough that max height matters? If max height is larger than the element would be naturally, max height won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the style to the event and not the target of the event.

Here I'm demonstrating two methods.

First, is a pure CSS method. This method uses :hover to change the style.

Second is javascript. This one uses the target of the event and toggles a class called zoom.

```js
const contacts = document.querySelectorAll(".contactjs");

const changeSize = (e) => {
  const el = e.target;
  el.classList.toggle("zoom");
};

contacts.forEach((c) => {
  c.addEventListener("mouseover",changeSize)
  c.addEventListener("mouseout",changeSize)
});
```

```css
.contactcss{
  height:1rem;
  background:red;
}

.contactcss:hover{
  height:20rem;
}

.contactjs{
  height:1rem;
  background:blue;
}

.contactjs.zoom{
  height:20rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactcss">CSS box</div>
<div class="contactcss">CSS Box2</div>

<div class="contactjs">JS box</div>
<div class="contactjs">JS Box2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! changing to querySelectorAll fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your functions slightly to affect the target of the event in question, like so:

```js
let bigger = function (event) {
  event.target.style.maxHeight = "10rem";
}

let normal = function (event) {
  event.target.style.maxHeight = "8rem";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need JS here (which you don't, see below) then notice that you're trying to do things to the `event` variable, which is (unsurprisingly) the JS event itself, it's not a page element.

If you want the page element, you need to work with [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

And then instead of setting `style` values directly, set a CSS class:

```js
function bigger({ target }) {
  target.classList.add(`big`);
}

function normal({ target }) {
  target.classList.remove(`big`);
}

function changeSize(button) {
  button.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
  button.addEventListener('mouseout', normal);
}

const contacts = document.querySelectorAll('.contact');
contacts.forEach(changeSize);
```

```css
.contact {
  background: gold;
}

.big {
  font-size: 130%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">our div</div>
```

Also note that this code uses `querySelectorAll`, because `getElementsByTagName` does not yield a result that has a `.forEach` function, whereas `querySelectorAll` does.

And on a final note relating to the kind of code you're currently writing: don't declare functions with `let somename = function(...)`, functions have been nameable from the very first day JS was released, just use that: `function nameYouWant(...)` and done.

However:

#### we don't need JS for this at all

This is something that CSS can already do all on its own, without any need for JS, because CSS has the `:hover` pseudo-selector that makes additional CSS kick in only when the cursor is hovering over an element:

```css
    .contact {
      background: gold;
    }

    .contact:hover {
      font-size: 130%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="contact">our div</div>
```

Barely any code, and it'll run even when people have JS blocked. This is infinitely better: don't use JS for this kind of thing. If you want to change styling, always check whether that's something you can just do with CSS and nothing else, because that's what CSS was designed and refined for over decades =)

Comment: Thanks!! it was more just to make sure i could make the javascript to work for learning purposes!

Comment: Just remember that part of learning JS is also knowing when _not_ to use JS =)

Answer (score 0):

Or this one...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.contact').forEach ( elm =>
  {
  ['mouseover','mouseout'].forEach( eTyp => 
    {
    elm.addEventListener( eTyp, () => 
      {
      elm.classList.toggle(`big`, eTyp === 'mouseover' );
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
.contact {
  background: gold;
}

.big {
  font-size: 130%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">our div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some issues with your code

1. The `event.style.maxHeight` is not a valid syntax. It should be `event.target.style.maxHeight`
2. The changeSize function is attempting to add event listeners to each element in the "first" NodeList, but the `forEach` method cannot be used on a NodeList. It should be `Array.from(first).forEach(changeSize);`.
3. The `mouseout` event listener is not valid here. it should be `mouseleave` to trigger the function when the mouse leaves the element.

here's the correct code

```
let first = document.getElementsByClassName('contact');

let bigger = function (event) {
  event.target.style.maxHeight = "10rem";
}

let normal = function (event) {
  event.target.style.maxHeight = "8rem";
}

let changeSize = function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
  button.addEventListener('mouseleave', normal);
}

Array.from(first).forEach(changeSize);
```

hope it helps you understand why your code is not working

Answer (score -3):

You are probably looking for onmouseover, not mouseover

Comment: I tried changing it to onmouseover but no difference

Comment: an inline listener would use `onmouseover` but with `addEventListener()`, you would use `mouseover`.

Comment: FYI - the *event* is `mouseover` - to add the event *in the HTML* you would use `onmouseover=` (don't do this, use javascript to add the event handler)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).